# Валидация email в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, валидация

Нужно написать функцию, которая проверяет введенный пользователем e-mail на соответствие следующим правилам:

1. e-mail состоит из имени и доменной части, эти части разделяются символом "@";
2. доменная часть не короче 3 символов и не длиннее 256, является набором непустых строк, состоящих из символов a-z 0-9_- и разделенных точкой;
3. каждый компонент доменной части не может начинаться или заканчиваться символом "-";
4. имя (до @) не длиннее 128 символов, состоит из символов a-z0-9"._-;
5. в имени не допускаются две точки подряд;
6. если в имени есть двойные кавычки ", то они должны быть парными;
7. в имени могут встречаться символы "!,:", но только между парными двойными кавычками.

Реализовано вот так, у кого какие мысли как еще можно сделать, ваши предложения и дополнения.

```
import re


def is_login(s):
    y, n, quo, pt = True, 0, False, False
    for c in s:
        if not y or n == 128 or (c in '!,:' and not quo) or \
           (c == '.' and pt) or not re.search(r'^[a-z0-9"._!,:-]$', c):
               y = False
               break
         n += 1
        if c == '"':
            quo = not quo
            pt = False
        else:
            pt = c == '.'
    y = s != '' and y and not quo
    return y


if __name__ == '__main__':
        for s in [
           '',
           'abc',
           'a' * 128,
           'a' * 129,
           'abc..def',
           'abc"."def',
           '"abc!,:def"',
           'abc!,:def',
           '"abc!,:def""',
           '""',
           '""#'
            ]:
            print('<{}>: {}'.format(s, is_login(s)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Смысла нет сильно напрягаться с валидацией. Потому что:

1. Даже в самый правильный валидатор можно вписать не существующий email
2. чем навернутее валидация тем больше вероятность ложного срабатывания FALSE

Вот например ваша валидация не пустит юзера если у него email на домене из кирилицы. А это уже не редкость.

PS Я еще когда то реализовывал проверку существования у домена MX записи. 
Этим можно проверить существования домена и обслуживаеться ли на этом домене почта

Comment: Это понятно, есть готовые библиотеки даже, но есть вот такое задание.

Comment: Тогда учтите ещё, что формат локальной части (до @) в принципе регулируется системой, обслуживающей домен. Ну и если коротко по одним лишь стандартам: 1. ПРОПИСНЫЕ буквы вполне допустимы, локальная часть может содержать прямое указание на имя папки (через символ #) и "детализацию аккаунта (через символ +).

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно отметили выше, любой валидатор можно обойти, но если все таки нужно хоть какое-то решение, то можно использовать следующий варианты:

1. Простенькая регулярка

```
import re
email = "me@host.com"

pattern = r"^[-\w\.]+@([-\w]+\.)+[-\w]{2,4}$"

if re.match(pattern, email) is not None:
    print("Проверка пройдена")
else:
    print("Провера не пройдена"
```

2. Другой вариант, автор [утверждает](https://emailregex.com/), что работает на 99.9%

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```